# Convert windows form application to Asp lr console application

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

I am using vs 2017rc and I have compatibility issues. I can't add windows form doll to my project and when I try to convert the code from win forms to Asp k get issues. Maybe I am doing it wrong but it seem to work on vs2015.

Please I need help to solve this. Maybe I am doing it wrong. See the code below.

```
using DotNetBrowser;
using DotNetBrowser.WinForms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetAjaxResponseBodySample
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static List<string> ajaxUrls = new List<string>();
    private WinFormsBrowserView browserView;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView();
        browserView.Browser.Context.NetworkService.ResourceHandler = new AjaxResourceHandler();
        browserView.Browser.Context.NetworkService.NetworkDelegate = new AjaxNetworkDelegate();
        Controls.Add(browserView);
        browserView.Browser.LoadURL("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_examples.asp");
    }

    private class AjaxResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
    {
        public bool CanLoadResource(ResourceParams parameters)
        {
            if (parameters.ResourceType == ResourceType.XHR)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Intercepted AJAX request: " + parameters.URL);
                ajaxUrls.Add(parameters.URL);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class AjaxNetworkDelegate : DefaultNetworkDelegate
    {
        public override void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedParams parameters)
        {
            if (ajaxUrls.Contains(parameters.Url))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Captured response for: " + parameters.Url);
                Debug.WriteLine("MimeType = " + parameters.MimeType);
                Debug.WriteLine("Charset = " + parameters.Charset);
                PrintResponseData(parameters.Data);
            }
        }

        private void PrintResponseData(byte[] data) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Data = ");
            var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
            Debug.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Am not concerned with the browser view... I already get the Jason I need from the Ajax response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Browser in a headless mode without creating BrowserView at all.

The following sample code works in the web application on VS2017rc with ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) or ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).
Please take into account that it is necessary to [Dispose browser](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000109699-disposing-browser) after the response body has been captured.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using DotNetBrowser;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication7.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static List<string> ajaxUrls = new List<string>();
        Browser browser;        

        public string Index()
        {
            Init();
            return "Test page";
        }        

        private void Init()
        {
            browser = BrowserFactory.Create();
            browser.Context.NetworkService.ResourceHandler = new AjaxResourceHandler();
            browser.Context.NetworkService.NetworkDelegate = new AjaxNetworkDelegate();

            browser.LoadURL("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_examples.asp");
        }       

        private class AjaxResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
        {
            public bool CanLoadResource(ResourceParams parameters)
            {
                if (parameters.ResourceType == ResourceType.XHR)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Intercepted AJAX request: " + parameters.URL);
                    ajaxUrls.Add(parameters.URL);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        private class AjaxNetworkDelegate : DefaultNetworkDelegate
        {
            public override void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedParams parameters)
            {
                if (ajaxUrls.Contains(parameters.Url))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Captured response for: " + parameters.Url);
                    Debug.WriteLine("MimeType = " + parameters.MimeType);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Charset = " + parameters.Charset);
                    PrintResponseData(parameters.Data);
                }
            }

            private void PrintResponseData(byte[] data)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Data = ");
                var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                Debug.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```